# Entity Framework and LINQ together Batch Update

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Afaik Entity Framework 6 doesn't support for batch insert/update/delete. 
Is there anyway to make an batch update over an IQueryable object. As an example I have

```
var query = _db.People.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(parameter));
```

an IQueryable (query) object and I want to get the generated sql. Then I hope I can create an update command with this select query like this

```
Update filteredPerson
Set filteredPerson.Status = 'Updated'
from (here it comes IQueryable Generated SQL :) ) as filteredPerson
```

over DbContext raw sql execution commands. BTW I don't need EF properties like change tracking and auto detecting. It is just a batch operation.

I know it is pretty risky but I am going to use it for a small piece of code.

Some other logics are appricated. If you know something better, I would like to hear it.

**REASON:** Why I want to do it this way, because I don't want to spoil the seperation of layers. And there is some validation and filtering comes into the queryable object from other layers. So it is hard to convert it to stored procedure. At the other hand it must be faster than other standard queries.

**Again I know there is no support in Entity Framework 6 for batch operations. But other questions are bit outdated. That's another reason why I want to ask this again.**

Comment: if this is a problem of perf, why don't you use a SP ? You can use SP with EF6... and the call to the sp could be in the "correct layer".

Comment: If I want to use SP then I have to pass same parameters which already  filtered in IQueryable. Ok, it is acceptable but sometimes it is hard to do, especially when you only take a queryable from another method. I can also call the sql command inside SP but mostly our business workflow in codebehind not in sql side. So I want to handle it in codebehind side not sql. Also I wanted to ask more generic question too not only customized for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I was writing the question, I was guessing how I am going to solve it. But I was looking for some more proper way of it. In the end, I know what am I doing and tried to be simple for my colleagues who looking to the same code after me. I know it has some risky usages but I let the exceptions to CLR to handle it. After this excuse :) , I wrote the code like this:

Let's say I have an IQueryable object which is generated with this way:

```
string parameter = "John";

AdventureWorks2012Entities _db = new AdventureWorks2012Entities();
var query = _db.People.AsQueryable();
//Some parameters added from different layers
query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(parameter));
```

Then I want a batch update over this IQueryable object.

```
var sqlFrom = query.ToString(); //This is the query which becomes "from table"
var dbq = query.AsDbQuery().GetObjectQuery(); //This does some magic with reflection

var linqParams = dbq.Parameters
    .Select(x => new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter(x.Name, x.Value)).ToList();
linqParams.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ModDate", DateTime.Now));

var sqlBatchUpdate = @"Update filteredPerson Set ModifiedDate = @ModDate From (@FilteredPerson) as filteredPerson"
    .Replace("@FilteredPerson", sqlFrom);
var affectedRows = _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlBatchUpdate, linqParams.ToArray());
```

That's it! Now I don't have to repeat same business logic in stored procedure again. And it is more faster than a foreach and SaveChanges combo.

So I ended up with this for very basic usage. As a fast solution It brings more problems no doubt! But I know I can easily wrap around it for new purposes. So It is up to programmer who wants to use it with more preferences.

Also the code which does the reflection and casting is below and I added a gist for full code:

```
public static ObjectQuery<T> GetObjectQuery<T>(this DbQuery<T> query)
{
    var internalQueryField = query.GetType()
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_internalQuery"))
        .FirstOrDefault();
    var internalQuery = internalQueryField.GetValue(query);
    var objectQueryField = internalQuery.GetType()
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_objectQuery"))
        .FirstOrDefault();
    var objectQuery = objectQueryField.GetValue(internalQuery) as ObjectQuery<T>;
    return objectQuery;
}
```

Here is the [Gist file](https://gist.github.com/yusufuzun/8673115). Hope It helps somebody out there.